# How to draw characters only partially using awt or another drawing mechanism?

Tags: java, drawing, awt

How can I draw a character or a sequence of characters only partially (e.g. only the upper half)?

The method `drawString()` of the `java.awt.Graphics` class only allows you to draw the characters entirety, but I want to show only the lower half for example.

Comment: For more sophisticated versions of 'partially visible' than a `Clip` can provide, consider using an opaque/transparent `GradientPaint` or `MulitpleGradientPaint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Graphics objects [clip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setClip%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

---

The code below produces this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JComponent() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            String text = "Hello World!";

            g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(40f));

            Rectangle2D b = g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(text, g);
            Rectangle2D bounds = new Rectangle2D.Double(100 + b.getX(),
                                                        100 + b.getY(),
                                                        b.getWidth(), 
                                                        b.getHeight() / 2);
            g.setClip(bounds);
            g.drawString(text, (int) bounds.getX(), 
                               (int) (bounds.getMaxY() + b.getMaxY()));
        }
    });

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```